# NETSUITE Rest API - How can I get the account number from these tables?

Tags: rest, netsuite

issue:

I have an sql query that works with a custom "specialfield1" in transactionline table:

```
{   "q": "SELECT * FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN transactionline tl ON t.id = tl.transaction where tl.specialfield1 IS NOT NULL and t.trandate >= '11/1/2021'"

}
```

However I need to also get the account number for these results.

I am not sure what field to match with the account table using the transaction - transactionline table???

Q: Can you let me know how to also retrieve the account number for this query using additional query matches and tables (account table)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with Accounts table

```
SELECT A.NAME,* FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN transactionline tl ON t.id = tl.transaction 
Inner join  Accounts  A on TL.ACCOUNT_ID=A.ACCOUNT_ID
where tl.specialfield1 IS NOT NULL and t.trandate >= '11/1/2021'
```